# Firefox Add-on - how to get post message on the page in add-on panel.html

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon

I bump into trouble in firefox add-on development.

[symptom]: 
can not receive message from firefox add-on bar's panel page, the message is sent from iframe on the panel.html.

here is my code:

/***  in file [popup.html] ***/
   // in the body i add an iframe element.

```
   iframe src="http://localhost/hello.html"
```

/*** in file [popup.js] ***/
   // I add a listener

```
   window.addEventListener("message", 
    function(event) {
        console.log("popupJS Receive Event from WebPage(" + event.origin);      
        console.log(event);
        //alert(event);
    });
```

/*** in the remote page hello.html ***/
   // I send the message by clicking .
*emphasized text*

```
   window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "http://dicrectpass.com");
```

=====>>
   But, I still can not receive the message from the iframe !!
   Why?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Then I realized I was including my Javascript from within the HTML document I was loading instead of via the Panel constructor. Once I switch that out, it worked fine.

[Panel reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Panel%28options%29)

```
var pnl = panel.Panel({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    contentURL: self.data.url('popup.html'),
    contentScriptFile: [
        self.data.url('jquery.js'),
        self.data.url('popup.js')
    ],
    onMessage: function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
});
```